# Problema con sentencia sql

Tags: sql

Necesito hacer esta sentencia select, pero me da error, me podeis ayudar?

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE country_id = "(SELECT country_id FROM users 
                     WHERE username=$username)"
```

Comment: Hola @Gonzalez, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Siempre tenes que agregar cual es el error que devuelve tu base de datos, y ademas agregar sobre cual estas trabajando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE country_id IN (SELECT country_id FROM users WHERE username=$username)
```

Comment: si, funciona bien gracias

Comment: Por favor edita y explica lo que hiciste para corregir la sentencia del OP, pues responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la respuesta de Julian soluciona el problema, no explica el mismo:

No se puede igualar un campo a una lista de valores, para ello en SQL se utiliza la sentencia IN, que nos permite igualar un valor a una lista de valores.

Sin embargo, en la query que estas mostrando, esto no tiene sentido, ya que estas pidiendo que iguale de la tabla users a si misma, utilizando un campo de si misma.

Para lo que estas buscando, se puede sacar totalmente el IN y hacer un query mas directo.

Fijate que lo que decis es, seleccionar de la tabla usuarios a todos los usuarios que cumplan que el pais este en la lista que dice seleccionar paises de la tabla usuarios donde el usuario sea igual al parametro. Esto no tiene sentido, mejor seleccionar directamente los paises de ese usuario asi:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE username=$username
```

Comment: Me extraña que los países sean el campo `name` en una tabla `users`, en cualquier caso.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.. pero me guio por lo poco que puso el usuario.. @JaimeDrq